# Cannot load play.http.errorHandler - custom handler not invoked

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework, customization, classnotfoundexception

I am attempting to load a custom error handler in Play Framework (2.6) as per [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling) but am receiving the following error message -

> Cannot load play.http.errorHandler

**Custom error handler (app/services/ErrorHandler)**

```
   package services

   import javax.inject.Singleton
   import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
   import play.api.mvc.Results._
   import play.api.mvc._

   import scala.concurrent._

   @Singleton
   class ErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

     def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
       Future.successful(
         Status(statusCode)(
           message
         )
       )
     }

     def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = {
       Future.successful(
         InternalServerError("A server errors occurred: " + exception.getMessage)
       )
     }
   }
```

**application.conf**

```
   play.http.errorHandler = "com.mySite.services.ErrorHandler"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the package isn't `com.mySite.services`. It's just `services`.

application.conf

```
play.http.errorHandler = "services.ErrorHandler"
```

Comment: Thanks. Caught this earlier today and was about to post. Discovered it's a nightmare to render a page in `onClientError` rather than a simple `String` message. Easy if just rendering the view, e.g. `views.html.myTemplate(title)` but not so if building the page via actions_